# Screen Retain unlock when our application is running

Tags: android, screen

Is it possible to make continuously unlocked the screen when our application is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). But it's not a good solution because you have to acquire and release it manually. And AFAIK it requires a permission. The better solution is to use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` for a view which requires screen to be on.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do that in xml with this option: android:keepScreenOn="true"...